# SQL Alchemy: DatabaseError when adding parent and child in the same session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQL Alchemy throws DatabaseError when I flush both child and parent from the session at the same time.

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'

    # Primary key - using two columns
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    split_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False, default=0, server_default='0')

    # Other columns...

class Child(Versioned, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    parent_id = Column(Parent.id.type, nullable=False)
    parent_split_id = Column(Parent.split_id.type, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            [parent_id, parent_split_id],
            [Parent.id, Parent.split_id],
            onupdate='cascade',
        ),
    )

    # Other columns...

    parent = relationship(
        'Parent',
        backref=backref('children'),
    )

parent = Parent()
parent.child = Child()

session.add(parent)
session.flush() # sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 1364 (HY000): Field 'child_id' doesn't have a default value
```

I'm parsing a spreadsheet and simply adding everything new into the session and then commit at the end. I make sure to reuse objects. But the `id` doesn't get assigned until I do a `session.flush()`, and when I do `session.flush()` my parent objects get flushed as well because there's a relationship with `backpopulates`.

What's the right sql alchemy way to deal with this? I cannot find anything relevant in the docs. It's all about setting up relationship.

Edit: Updated code with class samples. In my case, I use composite primary key, but it should be a problem. The error complains about child not having an id.

Comment: try to add default value to your child_id

Comment: I'm expecting the `child_id` to be autofilled from the assigned Child.id once it's created.

Comment: Added class examples. They are pretty huge, so I only added the way I form a relationship between them.